# How to connect the GND with the metal case of the robot

Tags: pcb-design, grounding, esd

I have a PCB design inside a metal case of the robot. The robot is mobile, it moves on wheels.
The problem is how to connect the GND with the metal case of the robot. Direct connection is not safe, the robot has static voltage after the long use and it is dangerous for circuits. 
I found some solution - the connection through parallel R and C, but I’m not sure of the correctness of it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Having charge build-up on the case isn't itself a problem, even if the board is grounded to the case. They're at the same potential.

The problem arises when the robot comes into contact with something at a different charge potential: the charge path may make its way though the sensitive stuff. So you need some countermeasures to route the charge away from where it can do harm.

Floating the electronics isn't such a great idea, because you're adding impedance to the discharge path. This will make your system *more* vulnerable to ESD, not less.

Instead, you should have two ground systems: shield (enclosure), and system (logic board). The two grounds should star-tie at the I/O connectors with a reliable, low-impedance connection. In this way no potential difference develops between the two, and there is a low-impedance path for ESD protection.

Speaking of which, the connector signals should have ESD protection that makes its own short tie to the shield and system GND star-tie. This isolates the discharge path away from the board and back to the enclosure.

You can also consider having the robot drag a ground strap to prevent build-up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a slow build-up of charge.

I would think it would still be fine to connect the PCB ground directly to the case since the circuit (if battery powered) will just float up to whatever the case is charged to.

It would be safer to connect it to the case through a 1-10 Megaohm resistor so the charges equalize more slowly. Similar to an ESD work mat compared to a conductive surface.

I don't see any point to the capacitor since that just lets a very speedy discharge occur which defeats the purpose of having a resistor there.

Why does charge build on the case anyways? That's the real question.